# gdb: way to show actual code being executed?

Tags: assembly, gdb

I'm learning how to program in assembly, and I want to see exactly what gdb is executing per line as I step through the program.  I know `display /i $pc` gives me the assembly code corresponding to what is being executed, but I want the object code (I think that's what it's called?)

So for example if I have the following:

```
    0:  c7 04 24 12 90 04 08    movl   $0x8049012,(%esp)
    7:  5d                      pop    %ebp
    8:  c7 45 00 28 54 8f 44    movl   $0x448f5428,0x0(%ebp)
    f:  89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
    11: 55                      push   %ebp
```

I want gdb to tell me that it's going through `c7 04 24 12 90 04 08` and not give me `movl   $0x8049012,(%esp)`.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind found a solution on my own:
`set disassemble-next-line on` gives me what I want.